# Syntax error when console logging an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects and I am not able to find the syntax error in it.

```
const hospitalInfo = [{ name: “celina”, lastName : “khalife”, dob:”10/08/1991”, age: 28}, { name: “simon”, lastName : “haddad”, dob:”10/08/1994”, age: 26}];
```

How can I fix the syntax error

Thank you

Comment: You're using "fancy quotes" `“`. Use regular quotes (copy this one if you need `"`)

Comment: Try `const hospitalInfo = [{ name: "celina", lastName : "khalife", dob:"10/08/1991", age: 28}, { name: "simon", lastName : "haddad", dob:"10/08/1994", age: 26}];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasting this into my console gives a link to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Illegal_character):

> What went wrong?
>
> There is an invalid or unexpected token that doesn't belong at this position in the code. Use an editor that supports syntax highlighting and carefully check your code against mismatches like a minus sign ( - ) versus a dash ( – ) or simple quotes ( " ) vs non-standard quotation marks ( “ ).

It looks like you're using the wrong quotes in your array. You should use either `'` or `"` to indicate a string literal in javascript.

Replacing all your quotes with `"` fixes this error:

```js
const hospitalInfo = [{ name: "celina", lastName : "khalife", dob:"10/08/1991", age: 28}, { name: "simon", lastName : "haddad", dob:"10/08/1994", age: 26}];

console.log(hospitalInfo);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you

Comment: No worries. Want to mark this as correct?

Comment: 7 mins to go and Ill unlock that level